# Proving lebesgue increasing convergence thm...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Im not curious about the proof itself.

Just want to know why

For arbitrary $c<\int f d\lambda $, if $I>c \rightarrow I \geq \int f d\lambda$

I have seen this kind of argument in some of proof of other theorems.
 Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This says "If $c$ is any number less than the integral, than $I$ is greater than $c$." If $I$ is greater than any number less than the integral, than $I$ is clearly not less than the integral (then it would be greater than itself), so it is greater than or equal to it.